# How to Draw most simple 3D objects in .Net Maui

Tags: 3d, rendering, maui

I want to port an old app to run on .net maui to be cross-plattform.

In the UI, I need also an 3d View, where I draw some lines and surfaces in 3d space. Only User interaction here is rotate and translate view as well as zoom. The data itself is result of simulation, no imported 3d moddel.

Model is updated with very low update rate (30s).

I didn't find such features in .net maui: are there cross plattform packages for that?

If Not, is there another cross plattform ui approach other than maui for this scope? Backend will be C#

Comment: https://unity.com/

Comment: There is no a such api in the .net maui can meet your requirement.

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft's Learn .NET MAUI page on `GraphicsView` (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/graphicsview) explains how you can use `GraphicsView` with your customized `IDrawable`. Through `IDrawable::Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect` you can directly populate the `GraphicsView` with rudimentary lines and polygons (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/draw).

Taking this one step further, you can get the `System.Numerics` NuGet package which offers vector and matrix classes for working with 3D coordinates.

For simple 3D geometric shapes where the faces are painted with a solid fill color, here are some classes:

```cs
// Face.cs
namespace Toolkit.Maui.Shapes3D;

public class Face
{
    public Color Color { get; set; } = Colors.Red;
    public IList<int> Vertices { get; set; }
}
```

```cs
// Shape3D.cs
using System.Numerics;

namespace Toolkit.Maui.Shapes3D;

public enum RenderMode
{
    Solid,
    Wireframe
};

public class Shape3D
{
    public IList<Vector3> Points { get; set; }
    public IList<Face> Faces { get; set; }
    public Matrix4x4 Transform { get; set; } = Matrix4x4.Identity;
    public float[] HiddenFaceDashPattern { get; set; } = new float[] { 2, 10};

    public Point Project(Vector3 pt, Point Center)
    {
        Vector3 pt2 = Vector3.Transform(pt, Transform);
        return new Point(
            Math.Round(Center.X + pt2.X / (1 - pt2.Z / 800)),
            Math.Round(Center.Y + pt2.Y / (1 - pt2.Z / 800))
            );
    }

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect, RenderMode Mode = RenderMode.Solid)
    {
        if (Points == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (Faces == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        List<Point> pts = new List<Point>(Points.Select(pt => Project(pt, dirtyRect.Center)));
        foreach (var f in Faces)
        {
            Point pt0 = pts[f.Vertices[0]];
            Point pt1 = pts[f.Vertices[1]];
            Point pt2 = pts[f.Vertices[2]];
            Point v1 = new Point(pt1.X - pt0.X, pt1.Y - pt0.Y);
            Point v2 = new Point(pt2.X - pt1.X, pt2.Y - pt1.Y);
            double vz = v1.X * v2.Y - v1.Y * v2.X;
            bool HiddenFace = (vz <= 0);

            if (Mode == RenderMode.Solid)
            {
                if (f.Color == Colors.Transparent) continue;
                if (HiddenFace) continue;
            }

            PathF path = new PathF();
            path.MoveTo((float)pts[f.Vertices[0]].X, (float)pts[f.Vertices[0]].Y);
            for (int i = 1; i < f.Vertices.Count; i++)
            {
                path.LineTo((float)pts[f.Vertices[i]].X, (float)pts[f.Vertices[i]].Y);
            }
            path.Close();

            if (Mode == RenderMode.Solid)
            {
                canvas.FillColor = f.Color;
                canvas.FillPath(path);
            }

            if (Mode == RenderMode.Wireframe)
            {
                canvas.StrokeColor = f.Color;
                canvas.StrokeSize = 1;
                canvas.StrokeDashPattern = HiddenFace ? HiddenFaceDashPattern : null;
                canvas.DrawPath(path);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here's a sample ViewModel that populates those classes:

```cs
// MainViewModel.cs
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Toolkit.Maui.Shapes3D.Sample;

public class MainViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public bool Wireframe { get; set; } = true;
    public RenderMode Mode => Wireframe ? RenderMode.Wireframe : RenderMode.Solid;

    public Shape3D Cube = new Shape3D()
    {
        Points = new List<Vector3>()
        {
            new Vector3() { X = -100, Y = -100, Z = -100 },
            new Vector3() { X = 100, Y = -100, Z = -100 },
            new Vector3() { X = -100, Y = 100, Z = -100 },
            new Vector3() { X = 100, Y = 100, Z = -100 },
            new Vector3() { X = -100, Y = -100, Z = 100 },
            new Vector3() { X = 100, Y = -100, Z = 100 },
            new Vector3() { X = -100, Y = 100, Z = 100 },
            new Vector3() { X = 100, Y = 100, Z = 100 }
        },

        Faces = new List<Face>()
        {
            new Face() { Vertices = new List<int> {1,0,2,3}, Color = Colors.Red },
            new Face() { Vertices = new List<int> {4,5,7,6}, Color = Colors.Orange },
            new Face() { Vertices = new List<int> {2,0,4,6}, Color = Colors.Yellow },
            new Face() { Vertices = new List<int> {1,3,7,5}, Color = Colors.White },
            new Face() { Vertices = new List<int> {0,1,5,4}, Color = Colors.Blue },
            new Face() { Vertices = new List<int> {3,2,6,7}, Color = Colors.Green }
        }
    };

    private IDispatcherTimer _timer;

    public EventHandler Frame;

    public Matrix4x4 Delta { get; set; } =
        Matrix4x4.Multiply(
            Matrix4x4.CreateRotationX((float)(0.3 * Math.PI / 180)),
            Matrix4x4.CreateRotationY((float)(0.5 * Math.PI / 180))
            );

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ToggleRenderModeCommand = new Command(() => ToggleRenderMode());
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(ToggleRenderModeCommand)));
        _timer = App.Current.Dispatcher.CreateTimer();
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(10);
        _timer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            Cube.Transform = Matrix4x4.Multiply(Cube.Transform, Delta);
            Frame?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        };
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public ICommand ToggleRenderModeCommand { get; set; }

    public void ToggleRenderMode()
    {
        Wireframe = !Wireframe;
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Wireframe)));
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Mode)));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

The `MainViewModel` is declared as a singleton so both the `MainPage` app can work with it as well as your `MainDrawable` can render from it.

```cs
// MainDrawable.cs
using Microsoft.Maui.Graphics;

namespace Toolkit.Maui.Shapes3D.Sample;

public class MainDrawable : IDrawable
{
    private MainViewModel _vm;
    private MainViewModel VM
        => _vm ??= ServiceHelper.GetService<MainViewModel>();

    public void Draw(ICanvas canvas, RectF dirtyRect)
    {
        VM.Cube.Draw(canvas, dirtyRect, VM.Mode);
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Toolkit.Maui.Shapes3D.Sample"
             x:Class="Toolkit.Maui.Shapes3D.Sample.MainPage">
    
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <local:MainDrawable x:Key="drawable" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid RowDefinitions="*,Auto">
        <GraphicsView
            x:Name="graphicsView"
            Drawable="{StaticResource drawable}"
            BackgroundColor="Transparent"/>
        <Button
            Grid.Row="1"
            Text="Toggle Render Mode"
            Command="{Binding ToggleRenderModeCommand}" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

A full working example of the above can be found here: https://github.com/stephenquan/Toolkit.Maui.Shapes3D

[image: DotNetCube.gif]